# How do I create an xml document using pre-existing etree elements with lxml and python?

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I am working with a large (≈ 50 MB) XML file which contains alphanumerically sorted (by word title) word-definition entries in the following format:

```xml
<xml>

    <p>
        <word>Word1</word>
        <pos>word #1 part of speech</pos>
        <def>Definition for word #1</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Word2</word>
        <pos>word #2 part of speech</pos>
        <def>Definition for word #2</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Word3</word>
        <pos>word #3 part of speech</pos>
        <def>Definition for word #3</def>
    </p>
    .....
    <p>
        <word>Word3812089</word>
        <pos>word #3812089 part of speech</pos>
        <def>Definition for word #3812089</def>
    </p>

</xml>
```

Provided that all the words which start with the same letter are adjacent to each other, how can I split this file up into 26 individual XML files by their first letters? 
for instance, if I have a file like this:

```xml
<words>

    <p>
        <word>Bar</word>
        <pos>n. </pos>
        <def>A straight piece of something</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Bear</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A large furry predator.</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Cat</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A small domesticated furry mammal</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Dim</word>
        <pos>adj.</pos>
        <def>Lacking in illumination.</def>
    </p>

</words>
```

How could I turn it into these:

```xml
<words_b>
    <p>
        <word>Bar</word>
        <pos>n. </pos>
        <def>A straight piece of something</def>
    </p>

    <p>
        <word>Bear</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A large furry predator.</def>
    </p>
</words_b>
```

```xml
<words_c>
    <p>
        <word>Cat</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A small domesticated furry mammal</def>
    </p>
</words_c>
```

```xml
<words_d>
    <p>
        <word>Dim</word>
        <pos>adj.</pos>
        <def>Lacking in illumination.</def>
    </p>
</words_d>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a grouping problem you can solve using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

import itertools as IT

xml = '''<words>
    <p>
        <word>Bar</word>
        <pos>n. </pos>
        <def>A straight piece of something</def>
    </p>
    <p>
        <word>Bear</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A large furry predator.</def>
    </p>
    <p>
        <word>Cat</word>
        <pos>n.</pos>
        <def>A small domesticated furry mammal</def>
    </p>
    <p>
        <word>Dim</word>
        <pos>adj.</pos>
        <def>Lacking in illumination.</def>
    </p>
</words>'''

words = ET.fromstring(xml)

for key, group in IT.groupby(words, lambda w: w[0].text[0]):
    group_element = ET.Element('words_' + key)
    for item in group:
        group_element.append(item)
    ET.dump(group_element, pretty_print = True)
```

Instead of dumping the `group_element` you could of course write it to a file.